# uitableviewcell update

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, asihttprequest

I have uitableview with cells.I download image asynchronous for each cell with ASIHttpRequest and put image into cell when it has been downloaded. Image downloads fine, but it puts when i click on cell, or scroll my uitableview. How to set image AND SHOW it immediatly?

```
    NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:photoURL];
   [request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{       
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
    }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
      //other code (cell.textLabe.text = ...) etc.
```

Here are screenshots with cell before click on it, and after:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `[tableView reloadData]` inside the completion block.

Comment: It's doesn't help:(
Only for first load. When i begin to scroll i see that images are wrongly exposed and slowly exposing to there places. On real device it will be with lags

Answer (score 0):

for updating tableview  use

[yourTableView reloadData]

and for download images asynchronously use

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Answer (score 0):

First guess, you defined your imageview or calling your image in delegate didSelectedRowAtIndexPath method therefore it appears when you click on cell. Basically to solve your problem,just move your code right in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.